# when I pres run on the upper left it works but when use f5 or ctr f5 , it shows the messages below, am a beginner so excuse me if it's stupid to ask

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

that's the first output

```
"[Running] python -u "C:\Users\20115\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python"
5

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.08 seconds"
```

the second and it appear from terminal not output! why

```
'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\20115\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '4683' '--' 'C:\Users\20115\Untitled-1.py'
```

I tried to reinstall vs and python but nothing changed.

Comment: read the VSC Python doc pages

Comment: am a beginner , can't u plz tel me am wasted the whole day

Comment: why should I copy the doc pages that are very clear to read

Comment: why are you using CodeRunner?

Comment: I got there but can't get to the problem, can u sent a link with my issue, plz

Answer (score 0):

First execute the script using the official extension **Python**, Your first result is obtained by *Code Runner* extension execution.

[image]

If your scripts all run successfully, you should check your code for output statements.